# Deleting a document on onClick event is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a chat application and trying to implement a function that deletes a clicked message on onClick event, but I am getting an error "index.esm2017.js:1032 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')".
I am using firebase for the database.
Could anyone look into what is wrong with my code?
Thank you.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const adminUid = "";

    useEffect(() => {
        const colRef = collection(db, "messages");
        const colRefOrdered = query(colRef, orderBy("createdAt"));

        onSnapshot(colRefOrdered, (snapshot) => {
            setMessages(
                snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                    return {
                        id: doc.id,
                        message: doc.data()
                    };
                })
            )
        })
    })

    const deleteHandle = async() => {
        const docRef = doc(db, "messages", messages.id);
        await deleteDoc(docRef);
    }

    if (adminUid === auth.currentUser.uid) {
        return (
            <div className="Chatroom">
                <div className="chatsChatroom">
                    {messages.map(({ message, id }) => (
                        <div>
                            <div key={id}
                                className={`msg ${message.uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? "sent" : "received"}`}>
                                <img src={message.photoURL} className="senderProfilePicture" />
                                <div className="senderName">
                                    <p> {message.displayName} </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="text">
                                    <p> {message.text} </p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="deleteChat">
                                    <h3 onClick={deleteHandle}> Delete </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>

                <SendMessage />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const docRef = doc(db, "messages", message.id);`? (And not `messages.id`)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I also tried message.id at the beginning but it still gets an error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the value of `messages.id` is probably undefined, this is because you are trying to access key `id` for an entire array of `messages`. What you need is just the `id` of the message that you wish to delete.
When you map the `messages` array to show each message, your `message` object must have a key `id`. You need to pass that value to your `deleteHandle` method:

```
<div className="deleteChat">
    <h3 onClick={() => deleteHandle(id)}> Delete </h3>
</div>
```

After this you need to accept the `message.id` value in your function's arguments:

```
const deleteHandle = async(msgId) => {
 docRef = doc(db, "messages", msgId);
 deleteDoc(docRef);
}
```

This will only pass the id of the message you wish to delete, I hope this helps. Please accept this as the answer if it does! Thanks

Comment: I rewrote my code as you mentioned, but message.id did not work as well. Instead I wrote id only and finally it is working. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unsure of where the value of `id` would be. Glad this helped, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick on the left, thanks!